# C# Create BigInteger from string of different base

Tags: c#, biginteger, numerics

How can I create a Numerics.BigInteger object from a string of another base in C#, like binary or hex string?

For example:

01101000001111100100100010001100010110000000100000000011000111011110111010111110

to

492275040001072000003774

Thanks!

Comment: @Nacimota That's not a duplicate, Answer there works only for `ToInt32` which doesn't fits OP's requirement.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you're quite right; I only just noticed that. Apologies, OP.